# Is there a way to configure journald.conf through cloud config on CoreOS?

Tags: systemd, coreos, journald, cloud-config

Try to find a way to automatically set `SystemMaxUse` for `systemd-journald.service`. I knew I can set it in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` manually. But it will restore to default after CoreOS updates in my experience.

Also, configuring `drop-ins` in `cloud-config` does not work because the default service definition file does not contain the `SystemMaxUse` field.

Is there a way to configure journald.conf through cloud config on CoreOS ? Or, is there a way to automatically set it ?

Answer (score 1):

> Try to find a way to automatically set SystemMaxUse for systemd-journald.service. I knew I can set it in /etc/systemd/journald.conf manually. But it will restore to default after CoreOS updates in my experience.

Updates will only touch /usr, which is read-only already. Anything written to /etc persists and can be managed, updated, whatever by you.

> Also, configuring drop-ins in cloud-config does not work because the default service definition file does not contain the SystemMaxUse field.

I believe a drop-in can add new parameters not present in the original service file, so this shouldn't be an issue. Did you run into this previously? You may need to do a `systemctl daemon-reload` and restart `systemd-journald` for the changes to be picked up.

> Is there a way to configure journald.conf through cloud config on CoreOS ? Or, is there a way to automatically set it ?

Writing this out via cloud-config and restarting `systemd-journald` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Like you said, I presumed CoreOS should not restore the `journald.conf` after updates, but it happened. Thus, I try to find a more reliable way to set the journald.conf. Besides, I use `drop-ins` and it showed `Unknown lvalue 'SystemMaxUse' in s...'Service'`